# Is there one wavefunction per field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, quantum-electrodynamics

Is the big picture of quantum field theory that:

- There are fields (EM, electron, Higgs, gravity, etc.)
- A field can be described by a wavefunction indicating the probability density of 1 or more 'particles,' which are just localizations/quantizations of the field
- One field affecting another is an 'interaction'

  - Would that mean that photons, as the force-carrier of the EM field, have their own field? I thought that photons were just localizations of the EM field.
  - Why aren't electrons similarly localizations of the EM field?

I know this is a very broad question for a Stack Exchange site, but I have yet to find a treatment that covers these questions that isn't either uselessly general (i.e. 'popular') or extremely, extremely specific (i.e. textbooks). Even the few in-between treatments seem to avoid these very fundamental concepts.

Comment: "*A field can be described by a wavefunction*" nope. No wfs in QFT. And "*One field affecting another is an 'interaction'*" is a rather vague and imprecise definition of "interaction". If a textbook is "extremely specific" for you, then I don't think we could do any better.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, thank you—I am using some textbooks, what I should have said is "I can't ask textbooks broad questions" and/or "I'd like to keep to just a few textbooks" :)

Comment: No, it's more complicated than that. A classical particle's position can be described by a number, while a quantum particle's state is described by a wavefunction, i.e. a function from positions to numbers. A classical field's configuration can be described by a function, and a quantum field configuration can be described by a 'wavefunctional', i.e. a function from functions to numbers. So the state of a quantum field is much, much 'larger'.

Comment: Electrons are a separate quantum field. Why would you think they should be part of the EM field? That isn't even true in classical mechanics.

Comment: @knzhou I think the role of charge in an EM field was throwing me off.

Answer (score 6):

In the quantum mechanical description of *any* physical system, including a quantum field or a collection of interacting quantum fields, there is always *one* state vector – one collection of numbers (probability amplitudes) that generalizes what is referred to as the "wave function" in quantum mechanics of particles.

In quantum field theory, a better name is a "wave functional". Just like for the wave function, it is a complex function on the configuration space. For example, for a coupled scalar and Maxwell field, the state vector is the wave functional
$$ \Psi [ \vec A(x,y,z), \Phi(x,y,z) ] $$
For every configuration of the field $\vec A$ and the field $\Phi$, there is one complex number. Usually, different bases than this "functionally continuous" bases are used to describe the wave functional.

At any rate, this wave functional is a function of infinitely many variables. It has enough information to "include" the particle-based wave functions $\psi(\vec x_1,\vec x_2,\dots \vec x_n)$ for an arbitrarily large number $n$ of particles.

For fermions such as electrons, the wave functional must also be a function of Grassmann (anticommuting) variables $\eta(x,y,z)$ describing the Dirac or Weyl or Majorana fields.

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly Fock states in second quantization are? Are they functions on Minkowski space or functionals over classical field configurations? I read about the Schrödinger functional that the quantum field operators are supposed to act on (analogously to how position operators act on QM wavefunctions) but now I'm confused because if Fock states are just plane waves (ie. functions of spacetime) how could quantum field operators act both on Fock space and a functional space over Fock states? Please explain it to me, I'm completely stuck.

Comment: Dear István, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space for a definition. A Fock space is the Hilbert space describing a free quantum field or fields. It is equivalent to an infinite-dimensional harmonic oscillator (one or several dimension for each value of the spacetime momentum). "The" Fock space states are usually the eigenvalues of the occupation number - each harmonic oscillator is excited N_k times, corresponding this many particles in the state with the momentum k.

Comment: The Fock space states are surely not waves in the ordinary spacetime. They are states of the quantum field. So if you represent the Fock space state in a position-like basis, the dimensions "x" where the wave functional is defined aren't spacetime coordinates. They are Fourier components of the field corresponding to a given momentum, $x_k, p_k$. Something like $x_k^2+p_k^2$ is the energy term from the $k$-labeled harmonic oscillator, up to a normalization, it is the number of particles with the momentum $k$.

Comment: The ground state of the Fock space is a second-quantized vacuum. It is a Gaussian wave function as a function of all these $x_k$ variables, so a product of Gaussians of the right width as a function of $x_k$ for every $k$. If you add a polynomial in $x_k$ in front of this Gaussian, you get the wave functional of an excited state, i.e. a state that has excited states at the $N_k$ level for the $k$ oscillator, corresponding to the occupation numbers $N_k$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I actually have gone through second quantization many times now. I understand that Fock space vectors are representing states of the field, that is they are vectors in an infinite dimensional vector space that is constructed by quantum harmonic oscillators. BUT why are you saying that the individual quantum harmonic oscillators are not functions of spacetime? In QM they are - complex functions on space coordinates.

Comment: I want to see what a state "looks like" (for a long time I didn't understand the concept of a tensor because it was always presented as an abstraction-- in fact all I needed to hear to imagine what it is was that a tensor is a matrix! Once I could put my hand on something concrete I instantly understood the abstraction too.) So are Fock states basically complex functions? If not, what kind of a mathematical entity are they? The S-matrix is supposed to bring one Fock state into another. What does it act on really? You can't just say it acts on |e-e+> because that is not a mathematical object.

Comment: Another example so you see what my concern is. I understand the abstractions - I want some concreteness. When I first studied quantum mechanics I was never shown what a wave function is. "The wavefunction is |psi>" -- they would say. I wanted something concrete like "the wavefunction is a complex function, something like psi (x,t)= (a/pi)^1/4e^y^2/2 ". It all became clear when I saw it as a real thing not just some sort of out-of-this-world abstraction. Sorry if this looks stupid to a professional - I'm not a physics student just a curious guy.